# unity bake light for moving objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

Im pretty new to Unity3D a feel a bit lost in the interface so detailed instructions will be welcome.

I have some elements (prefab of model modeled in blender) that I want to pre-render using bake light, but that afterwards I want to move around. The game is gonna run on a phone (google cardboard).

I don't care about the changes of light because it won't change that much. For instance a picture in the wall that can "be opened" to show a secret passage. This picture won't change that much in space and if its lightning is a bit off.. it Won't matter.

Same goes for cockpit instruments. They have they own lights and I'd like to bake them. But then the cockpit will be moving around the scene.

I tried to mark those element as static, then render, then un-mark the static tag. So far it kind of works. I get the object lit and I can move them around BUT, the light depends on the orientation of the object! when I rotate the object (after bake it) its brightness depends on the angle .. I want it to be static light-wise!  Or at least, to have the expected lightning when it is in the position that it was when the light was baked. Why it get's the light when I turn it AGAINST the light ?

[image]

Here I show the properties of the object[image]

And the properties of the imported model [image]

Answer (score 2):

I FOUND IT !
You baked in directional mode (specular or not).
When you bake in directional, you can never rotate the object afterward, or it will mess completely the bake of directionnality.

Comment: This is the solution. In the Lighting Setting inside the Scene Tab change "Directional Mode" from Directional to Non Directional. Unity2020.1.8f1

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, if light is baked, lighting stays the same, its BAKED. This is the main reason baking light is only used for static objects.

Solution,
Bake ambient occlusion into your object in 3D package, and leave object dynamic in unity as it is dynamic! (You are moving it). This way will give you nice soft shadows prepared in your 3Dpackage and still work with pixel lighting in Unity

Comment: if light is baked why illumination changes when I turn the picture? (see picture, when rotating the picture hanging in the wall it get's brighter) There is no real time lights at all in the scene. Anyhow, can you develop the "bake ambient light in your object in 3D package" ??

Comment: You must confuse the light change with the specularity or other shader effects, or there is a internal Unity bug in Enlighten system (there are many at the moment)

Comment: I did the weirdest of the hacks, I turned the picture in the space, set to static, baked the light, un set static, turned back to position and BAM now it brights nicely. So confirm. The brightness of the object depends on its rotation. Does that make sense to anyone out there?

Comment: You don't need to check/uncheck Static, You can simply tick Lightmap static only (under little menu on the right of the Statick tickbox), this will leave static batching off and you will be able to move the Game Object around

Comment: Great! That's a nice tip :)  Any idea why the brightnes of an "Lightmap static" element changes when I turn it around ?

Comment: As I said if you bake it the albedo should stay the same, its reflection? Any Smoothness on the material?

Comment: there is no lights in the scene, can it be the albedo anyhow?

Comment: You need to revisit your question then. Screengrab is clearly showing 3 light gizmos in the scene

Comment: I edited the picture to one with the lights properly turned out. Since they where Baked I did not care to take them out. Hope it helps you with a solution for this...

Comment: So where is the current lighting coming from?

Comment: baked. Is a interior room with no light other than the bulbs that are baked. Is a FPS with no avatar for the player. Everything is baked (so far)